# Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, sqlite, genymotion

Estou tentando usar o android device monitor para extrair o meu banco de dados, só que fica dando esse erro.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

repare nos toll-tips

[image: push]

[image: pull]

pelo que eu entendi se voce quer pegar a file do seu device e salvar no seu computador voce tem que usar o **pull** escolha onde voce quer salvar essa file e se vc quiser colocar uma file no seu device voce usa o **push** e escolha qual file vc quer salvar no seu device